# The 'Get-azVM' command was found in the module 'Az.Compute', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, az

I have used Az module in powershell script which is getting executed from powershell core but getting error while executing the script from application (.Net core SDK 2.1).

> $VMExistanceCheck = Get-azVM -ResourceGroupName $VMResourceGroup -Name
>   $NewComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

I checked that Az.Compute module had been imported there.

I added `Import-Module Az.compute -verbose -force` inside the script also.

I got the following error while the script is getting invoked from application using runspace(System.Management.Automation, Version=6.1.0.0):

> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The 'Get-azVM' command
>   was found in the module 'Az.Compute', but the module could not be
>   loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Compute'. --->
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The 'Get-azVM'
>   command was found in the module 'Az.Compute', but the module could not
>   be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Compute'.

'Get-Module -ListAvailable ' shows that Az.Compute module is avilable but while the command 'import-module Az.Compute' is executed using Powershell 6, nothing is importing.

Comment: You can provide more details about what error do you get? If all the Azure PowerShell cannot execute? And do you log in before you execute the Azure PowerShell?

Comment: Can you post complete error exception message >

Comment: Do you set the execution policy for your local machine?

Comment: yes. I have already set it to unrestricted

Comment: Is it only Az.compute module can't be used?

Comment: Add-AzAccount and Login-AzAccount are executing inside the script before the 'Get-azVM' command

Comment: You can try to import the Az.compute module before running the script.

Comment: 'Import-Module Az.compute -verbose -force' is there at the beginning of the script.I had also added 'Import-Module -Name Az.Accounts ' which is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the log of PowerShellCore/Operational from Event viewer and found the following error:

Error Message = Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621)
Fully Qualified Error ID = System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

I have installed Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and finally the powershell script is getting invoked and the Get-AZVM command is successfully getting executed.

Comment: This package has been deprecated. See https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/ .

It appears to have been replaced by multiple packages Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue, and Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.

Answer (score 6):

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
```

Run that command.  Restart Powershell.  Run `import-module az.compute` again